# What is the MasterPageFile attribute path to choose for Application Page placed inside list definition?

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, visual-studio-2015

I want to use my application page as custom NewForm.aspx for the list. So I configured list's Schema.xml to use new Form:

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewRequestPage.aspx" Path="NewRequestPage.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

Then I added application page into my list definition subfolder in the following way: [image: my application page properties]

The issue consist in error that occurs when item creation page is called:

> File /mhp-clean-evr/Lists/VisitRequestsList/masterurl/default.master
>   does not exist

Currently MasterPageFile attribute value is "~masterurl/default.master".

What MasterPageFile attribute value to use to make my custom new form work?

Unfortunately I couldn't find an answer for this question yet.

Comment: **Solution:**  Manually configure MasterPageFile property via changing it from PreInit event: ` protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Override master page
            this.MasterPageFile = "../../_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master";
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Try MasterPageFile attribute as

```
MasterPageFile="/_catalogs/masterpage/default.master"
```

Comment: In this case I receive error: **The resource cannot be found. HTTP 404. Requested URL: /mhp-clean-evr/Lists/VisitRequestsList/NewRequestPage.aspx**   I think this is quite strange because location of the page wasn't changed.